# Deleting password works like passwd -l instead of enabling user to log in without it (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: login, password, passwd

I deleted user's password using `sudo passwd -d username`. In Debian it enables user to log in to his account without need to type the password (`su username` simply opens new shell for chosen user). In Ubuntu (18.10) it works basically like `passwd -l`, making account unusable until password is set again by root account.

Why the difference, what is the setting responsible for this behavior and how can I change it, so I can set a real blank password?